# How does List<Integer> in Java distinguish between element and index when an integer is passed?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list

In the abstract type List, how does it determine the argument is an index or element? 
For example, if a LinkedList calls remove(1), how does computer know whether it's removing the second element or the integer element with value 1?

Thank you!

Comment: LinkedList remove(int index)
Removes the element at the specified position in this list.

Comment: @Blasanka There are two `remove` methods, and understanding which one gets called requires a little more knowledge of some Java's intricacies.  It's not just a matter of reading the javadoc.